# leftmost bracket causing issues on line 10

Tags: python

```
def main():

    try:
        # open file
        inputFile = open('text1.txt', 'r')
        # read file into the list
        textfile = inputFile.read()
        # stip /n from each entry
        for i in range(len(textfile)):
        textfile[i] = textfile[i].rstrip('\n')
        words = textfile.split()
        print ('the number of words in the file is ', len(words))
    except:
        print('error occured')
main()
```

printing error occured, cannot find any solutions online.
has something to do with using read instead of readlines i think

Comment: Fix your indentation and try again

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: One or more lines after `for i in range(len(textfile)):` need to be indented but aren't. Fix your indentation and also show us the actual full error traceback, please.

Comment: `textfile` is a single string.  It is not a list of lines.  So, your `for` loop is going to loop over EACH CHARACTER in the string.  Thus, your assignment will fail because you can't change a string.  Just delete the `for` loop and the line after, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an indentation on the for loop code.

```
def main():

    try:
        # open file
        inputFile = open('text1.txt', 'r')
        # read file into the list
        textfile = inputFile.read()
        # stip /n from each entry
        for i in range(len(textfile)):
            textfile[i] = textfile[i].rstrip('\n')
        words = textfile.split()
        print ('the number of words in the file is ', len(words))
    except:
        print('error occured')
main()
```

Try this